# What's the probability of a population mean from normal distribution will be greater than zero having some samples?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

We've got normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma)$ and sampled results:
$[-5, 5, -10, 15, 25, 10, 0, 20, 10, 30]$. How to calculate probability of population mean will be greater than zero?

$\hat{\mu} = 10$

$\hat{\sigma} \approx 12.25$

$n = 10$

$P(\mu > 0) = ?$

Comment: If there is no prior on $\mu$ this is an ill-formed question since $\mu $ is deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I think I found the answer. Variable $\hat{x}$ is distributed $N(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$ which makes the whole problem easier. How should I formulate the question? @FoobazJohn